# how to properly install mlflow?

Tags: r, installation, mlflow

I followed the official document but found error

```
> install.package("mlflow")
Error in install.package("mlflow") : 
  could not find function "install.package"
> install.packages("mlflow")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/fzhu/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.2/mlflow_1.28.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 237435 bytes (231 KB)
downloaded 231 KB

package ‘mlflow’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\fzhu\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpgzY6Uy\downloaded_packages
> mlflow::install_mlflow()
Error in mlflow_conda_bin() : 
  Unable to find conda binary. Is Anaconda installed?
  If you are not using conda, you can set the environment variable MLFLOW_PYTHON_BIN to the path of your python executable.
> Sys.getenv("MLFLOW_PYTHON_BIN")
[1] "C:\\py310\\python.exe"
> Sys.getenv("MLFLOW_BIN")
[1] "C:\\py310\\Scripts\\mlflow"
```

any help is appreciated!

refer:
https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/issues/6738

Comment: From looking at `/mlflow/issues/6738`, it seems you should be able to `library(mlflow)` after `install.packages(` rather than taking the (unnecessary) next step of `::install_mlflow()`.

Comment: @Chris  Thanks! It sounds like this error doesn't affect the functionality. the documentation is confusing.

Comment: Have you tried `library(mlflow)` then played with examples?

Comment: yes. i did. after that i did mlflow_ui() and it doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

According to mlflow documentation, You need first install mlflow python package:

```
pip install mlflow
```

In the latest version of mlflow R package there's no more `mlflow::install_mlflow()` function.

The official R API documentation is here https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/R-api.html